# Iterate through API response to check for headers and index

Tags: apex, callout, httprequest

In my Apex class I'm making a request to an API to retrieve data. The API returns the data in the form of a CSV string.

**Apex:**

```
    public static String callMyAPI() {      
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
        httpRequest.setMethod('GET');
        httpRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        httpRequest.setHeader('Accept', 'text/csv');
        String crtNo = '<my cert>';
        httpRequest.setClientCertificateName(crtNo);
        httpRequest.setEndpoint(<my API endpoint URL>);
        httpRequest.setTimeout(60000); 
    
        String response = '';
        string responseBody;
        try {  
            Http http = new Http();   
            HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest); 
            if(httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200 ) { 
                responseBody = httpResponse.getBody();
            }
        } catch { //catch exception }
    
        return responseBody;
    }
```

The API is being updated to use pagination, i.e., the initial call will return the first page of data containing x number of rows.

I need to pass an initial index value as part of the endpoint (ex: `<my API endpoint URL>&pageIndex=1`), and once the response is returned, iterate through it to check for a new header:

**YAML:**

```yaml
    headers:
        Next-Page-Index:
            description: Non-empty, positive number indicates (1) there is a next page and (2) what its page index is
            type: string
```

If the `Next-Page-Index` header indicates there are more pages, I need to iteratively update the `&pageIndex` value and then call the API again to get the next page, and so on after each response until all data is returned. Then I need to add those responses together in a single string.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you know all of the individual parts here (append results to a string, look for a specific header, update the endpoint for your callout, make another callout). Where is it that you're stuck?

Comment: @DerekF I'm stuck a few things: 1) when the first response returns, how to go through the headers to see if `Next-Page-Index` has a value, 2) if it does, how can I apply that to the `&pageIndex=` query for the API endpoint to get the next page of data, and 3) make the API again while holding onto the first piece of data returned. So basically, making an individual API call is fine, but all these other pieces to support pagination with the API to get more data, that's where I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be out-thinking yourself here. Documentation is almost always a good starting place to look.

#### Starting with checking the header

The [HttpResponse class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm) has a `getHeader(key)` method.

So `String nextIndex = httpResponse.getHeader('Next-Page-Index');` is all you need. It'll be null if the header doesn't exist.

#### Updating the callout endpoint

Just store the base url as a string, and then append '&pageNum= nextIndex' if nextIndex isn't null.

If you want to be slightly fancier, you could use `String.format()`

#### Keeping previous results

Just simply define a string, and append the results of each callout to it.

```
String concatResult = '';

// first callout here //
// getBody() returns a string, so there shouldn't be anything else you need to do
//   (except for potentially base64 decoding)
concatResult += httpResponse.getBody();

// second callout here //
concatResult += httpResponse.getBody();
```

#### Putting things together

Since you're making an unknown number of callouts, you'll want to perform the callout in a loop. I think this is one of the few occasions where it makes sense to use a do-while loop.

In pseudocode

```
// set up the common http request bits (method/headers/cert)
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.headers = values
req.method = get
req.cert = private key

Http sender = new Http()

String baseEndpoint = https://my.third.party.tld/resource
String nextIndex;
// Gotta have an empty string if we want to append things to it (can't append things
//   to null)
String concatResult = '';

// You'll be making at least one callout, and the result dictates if you
//   make another
// Perfect scenario for a do-while
do{
    // I don't think there's a great way around doing a null check on
    //   nextIndex, so might as well just handle both cases in the loop
    req.setEndpoint(baseEndpoint + (String.isNotBlank(nextIndex) ? '&pageIndex = ' + nextIndex : ''));

    response = sender.send(req)
    nextIndex = response.getHeader('your target header');
    concatResult += response.getBody()
}while(nextIndex is not blank);
```